# Assertions with Selenium::Webdriver::Element object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm very new to using Selenium Webdriver (and Cucumber), but they're skills I'll need for a position that I'm very interested in at the moment, so I'm really trying to get a handle on how they work.

Here's the section of the feature I'm currently trying to test (using Selenium in conjunction with Cucumber):

```
Background:
  Given I am on the Shoe Store's home page

Scenario: Display New Releases for January
  When I click on the link "January"
  Then I should see a small blurb for each shoe
  And I should see an image for each shoe
  And I should see a suggested price for each shoe
```

And here are the relevant steps:

```
When(/^I click on the link "(.*?)"$/) do |month|
  step %[I click on link having text "#{month}"]
end

Then(/^I should see a small blurb for each shoe$/) do
  blurbs = $driver.find_elements(:class_name, 'shoe_description')
  if blurbs
    blurbs.each do |blurb|
      # Need to assert that blurb elements exist / have text
    end
  end
end
```

The second step is where I can't seem to find a clear answer. If I throw in a binding.pry I can see that I have all the objects I need to iterate through (blurb is a single webdriver object, and when I call blurb.text it shows the exact text that I'd like to assert exists).

It seems like this should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to just fail if the blurb does not have text. That would make your blurb loop into the following:

```
blurbs.each do |blurb|
  fail 'blurb contains no text' if blurb.text == ''
end
```

This will fail out the step and the scenario if the text is empty. You could also expand this to checking that the text matches expected text by comparing the text to the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

One simple assert will do the trick, you can verify that blurb.text is not blank like:

```
Then(/^I should see a small blurb for each shoe$/) do
  blurbs = $driver.find_elements(:class_name, 'shoe_description')
  if blurbs
    blurbs.each do |blurb|
      # Need to assert that blurb elements exist / have text
      blurb.text.should_not eq ""
    end
  end
end.
```

Hope this helps :)